# Skipping arguments/parameters without using empty strings

Tags: javascript

Theoretically speaking, let's say I have a function that takes 100 parameters and I only want to use 1 of these, and it's the 100th one. Instead of writing 99 empty strings before I can pass the 100th one, is there an easier way of doing this? I know you should never have 100 parameters but I got curious if this is even possible.

Comment: Assuming you should ever do this - which you should not, you should use an object with named properties as your argument(s) - you can use 'null' for the spaceholders.

Comment: No. This is impossible with JavaScript, or any language for that matter. (as far as my knowledge reaches)

Comment: @MarkGabriel Python has optional and named arguments (in which case order does not matter).

Comment: @MarkGabriel C# has optional and named arguments too.

Comment: Yes, but you have to indicate the variable/key name, which would be the JavaScript equivalent of JSON usage as an argument, which uses keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter objects - you can easily set defaults and override what you want with the parameter

```
var foo = myFunction({foo:'bar', bar:25})
```

Google parameter objects, eg [Passing Default Parameter Objects in JavaScript](http://ardalis.com/passing-default-parameter-objects-in-javascript)

(but if you've got more than 3 or 4 parameters you might have a more serious problem)

Comment: Didn't even think of using objects, but at least now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, yes, there is a way of doing this. It uses `Function.prototype.apply`, which allows you to use an array to provide the parameters for a function call.

So if our function was called `someFunc`, you could do this:

```
var params = Array(99); // array with 99 undefined parameters
params.push('foo'); // add the 100th parameter

someFunc.apply(null, params);
```

As you say, though, this is a *seriously* bad idea. A much better approach is to use an object with named values.

Comment: How about `someFunc.apply(null, Array.apply(null, { length: 99 }).map(function () { return ""; }).concat(arg100))`?

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes, if empty strings are required. I presumed `undefined` would do the job just as well.